# Download exe from sun httpserver in java

Tags: java, file, httpserver

I created a http server using sun httpserver and i want to download an exe file from the local machine from that code.
But code return the 'file' type file instead of '.exe' file.

I am adding the code here-

```
String fileName="D:\\test\\version\\"+dirFiles.lastEntry().getKey()+"\\"+dirFiles.lastEntry().getValue();
      System.out.println("fileName---"+fileName);

      File file=new File(fileName);
      System.out.println(file.isFile());
      System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
      System.out.println(file.canExecute());
      System.out.println(file.exists());
      t.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
      OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
      FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("D:\\test\\version\\2\\1.exe");
      final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
      int count = 0;
      while ((count = fs.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
        os.write(buffer,0,count);
      }
      fs.close();
      os.close();
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  When you say: *"But code return the 'file' type file instead of '.exe' file."* what exactly do you mean?  Something with the Content-Type header?

Comment: Check the content of the outputstream, redirect it to a file next to the original and compare them. If they are the same, might be a request problem

Comment: @selbie basically file gets downloaded but the file type is not exe. When we check the properties of this file, its file type is 'file'

Comment: @AxelH I did not understand what you are actually saying.Can you show it programatically

Comment: `When we check the properties of this file` - what do you mean by this?

Comment: @krati no... but since you've just said that this was just the extension of the file that was not correct, I would check how the file is recreated on the other side ...

Comment: Actually the file i am calling is "1.exe" but downloaded file name is 'get' but it has same size as "1.exe"

Comment: @krati, this is because the client downloading the file store the response of your request (so only the content) into a new file. File he named `get` without any extension. If the name is important, you should add it to the reponse (using a specific format) and do the client read it correctly. If not, only change the name of the file of the client side from `get` to `get.exe`

Comment: Can you please tell me,for downloading exe in sun httpserver code,which mime type i need to use.I tried 'application/octet-stream' but .exe file is still not downloaded

Comment: it is downloaded .. this is just the name (extension) that is incorrect. You said before that the files had the same size so this is downloading correctly. Please try to be precise with what you want. For the name of the file store on the client side, I have no idea of how this is done so I can't help.

Comment: My requirement is to download an exe file from executing this httpserver code.If i implement this in servlets,it gives me expected output. But i do not want to use servlets thats why i code my own httpserver. But httpserver code does not give me the actual exe